# What does this Laravel route statement exactly mean?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am new to Laravel and exploring existing project code. In the route, I found the expression below:

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod']);

Can someone clarify the second argument of this expression array - ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod']?

I was not able to find the description of it in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as` is a [route name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes). You can use it to build links with `route()` helper.

`uses` is an action. It's a controller and method that will be executed.

You can see an example in [old docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('user/profile', [
    'as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);
```

Comment: Spasibo for the info Alexey.

Answer (score 0):

The 'as' part is for "naming the route" so you can access the route by its name.
[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes).

The 'uses' part says "use the someMethod method in SomeController" and do whatever is in that method.